# Unable to link executable .jar file

Tags: symbolic-link

I am new to ubuntu linux command-line.
I am trying to link an executable .jar file in a folder that I added to the PATH. The folder is /software_library/bin which is the default PATH, where I should get the .jar file linked and named trimmomatic.

However, the ln -sf command is giving me a .zip file instead of the .jar file in my folder called bin, and I am unable to execute the program by just typing trimmomatic.

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write an script:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar your_jar_file
```

Save this script as trimmomatic. Then give permissions:

```
chmod +x trimmomatic
```

Put this script in your /.../bin

Comment: OK, I can now run the program with $ bash trimmomatic